# Asynchronous Payments with Django and Celery

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery, payment

I was wondering if anyone knows a way to take payments Asynchronously using django and celery. My desired process would be this:

1. Client submits payment form
2. Request is sent to Django
3. The request is passed to celery to do the work
4. Django closes the request by returning a response
5. Client is then notified when the payment has complete

I'd like to do this without polling.

How would I get the "payment complete" signal back to the client if the original request was closed? Would some kind of node/tornado integration be possible here?

Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#task-success

Comment: You could send an email from celery when payment is completed.